# Does an ontology has any impact on the Marklogic triple index?

Tags: indexing, marklogic, ontology

In `Marklogic 9`, with a very large set of triples loaded, some SPARQL queries were very slow even if the triple index option was enabled.  At that time, billions of data triples were loaded but no ontology triples at all were.  After the load of the ontologies, the performance has improved a lot.

I don't believe that's because of the ontologies because my queries are not referring to them at all.  But it seems that the triple index were only effective after the load of the ontologies.  This is the first time I encountered such a situation.  Usually, the data triples can be queried effectively without any ontology.

Any clue why?

Comment: Were you running sparql queries *while* loading triples/ontologies? Is it possible to share an example query that seemed to run slow at first?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a coincidence. There must be some other explanation for the slower/faster queries.